# Django Many to Many Relationship on both models

Tags: python, django

I am building a small web application where people will be able to join shows and for it to show that they joined it on a template. However, my current problem is that on my `User Profile` model I have added a couple of shows but the `Show` model object doesn't show that the User Profile is apart of it. How can I achieve this in Django?

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True, related_name='user')
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to="uploads/profile")
    show = models.ManyToManyField('Show', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)


    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

    post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)


class Show(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="uploads/show")
    venue = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: You should show how you added the items, and how you're trying to display them.

Comment: I selected the shows in the django admin menu. @DanielRoseman

Comment: Looking at the show in the django admin, it isn't selected there.